# Transforming table of categorical data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two columns Status and Verified Status that I want to transform to columns for each of their unique values for counts. How exactly can I do this in SQL Server?

Input

```
Year   Status     Verified_Status
---------------------------------
2021   Accepted   Verified
2021   Accepted   Verified
2021   Rejected   Unverified
2021   Accepted   Unverified
2021   Accepted   Unverified 
2020   Rejected   Unverified
2020   Accepted   Unverified
2020   Accepted   Unverified
```

Expected output

```
Year  Accepted Rejected Verified Unverified
-------------------------------------------
2021  4        1        2        3
2020  2        1        0        3
```

Comment: Have a research into "conditional aggregates".

Answer (score 1):

As Larnu alluded to... a simple conditional aggregation should do the trick

```
Select Year
      ,Accepted   = sum( case when [Status]='Accepted' then 1 else 0 end )
      ,Rejected   = sum( case when [Status]='Rejected' then 1 else 0 end )
      ,Verified   = sum( case when [Verified_Status]='Verified' then 1 else 0 end )
      ,Unverified = sum( case when [Verified_Status]='Unverified' then 1 else 0 end )
 From  YourTable
 Group By Year
 Order By Year Desc  -- << Optional
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
        Count(Case When Status = 'Accepted' then 1 end) Accepted,
        Count(Case When Status = 'Rejected' then 1 end) Rejected,
        Count(Case When Status = 'Verified' then 1 end) Verified,
        Count(Case When Status = 'Unverified' then 1 end) Unverified
    from T group by year
```

Comment: Missed Year, Verified_Status column and group by